# pass 1 of several different classes to a Function as an argument

Tags: vb.net

I have several classes which define data structures with a sub to add the values as a string().

e.g.

```
class A
  public property a1 as string
  public property b1 as integer
 Public sub Add(Input as String())
  a1 = input(0)
  b1 = input(1)
 end sub
end class 

class B
  public property c2 as integer
  public property d2 as string
  public property e2 as string
 Public sub Add(Input as String())
  c2 = input(0)
  d2 = input(1)
  e2 = input(2)
 end sub
end class
```

I want to be able to pass either class a or class b to a function for use as a type in a List(of t).

e.g.

```
List(of A) = Function_C(PathToFile, A)
or
List(of B) = Function_C(PathToFile, B)

Function Function_C(Path as string, curDatClass as object) as list(of object)
  dim retVal as List(Of Object)
  Using MyReader As New TextFieldParser(DatafilePath)
            With MyReader
                .TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited
                .Delimiters = New String() {vbTab}
                'Loop through all of the fields in the file.
                While Not .EndOfData
                    Dim currentRow As String()
                    currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields
                    curDatClass.Add(currentRow)
                    retVal.Add(curDatClass)
                End While
                Return retVal
            End With
        End Using
  retVal = Nothing
End Function
```

Since each class has its own Sub Add to pass an array of values to the properties, the number of properties should not matter and therefore a generic sub similar to the above should work for all similar classes.

```
List(of A) = Function_C(PathToFile, A)
```

The above gives me the error "A is a classtype and cannot be used in an expression"

I can't find a vb.net example of how to generically pass the class/type as an argument and return the function as the generic class/type to a strongly typed list.

The above code (stripped down for brevity) hopefully give you an idea of what I want to do.

My searching came up with nothing of value. It could be that I'm not sure how to ask the question, so here I am now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what interface and generics are for. If both class have the same function, they can implement an interface. Your function can take that interface as parameter. As for the return value, you'll have to use a generic function. I suggest you look more into those two concept.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim objectA As New ClassA
    Dim objectB As New ClassB

    Dim listA As List(Of ClassA) = SomeFunction(Of ClassA)(objectA)
    Dim listB As List(Of ClassB) = SomeFunction(Of ClassB)(objectB)

End Sub

Function SomeFunction(Of T As SomeInterface)(ByVal input As T) As List(Of T)

    Dim returnValue As New List(Of T)

    input.Add()

    returnValue.Add(input)

    Return returnValue
End Function

Interface SomeInterface

    Sub Add()

End Interface

Class ClassA
    Implements SomeInterface

    Public Sub Add() Implements SomeInterface.Add

    End Sub

End Class

Class ClassB
    Implements SomeInterface

    Public Sub Add() Implements SomeInterface.Add

    End Sub

End Class
```

As for your code, I suggest you turn Option Strict On. You'll see some problems. Also, I don't think retVal will have the content you want since you are adding the same object all the time.

Comment: I won't mark this as answered yet as I need to read up on what you've given me and I may have more questions before I understand it. Tks

Comment: @Don6558 start by understanding interface or inheritance (with a base class). Try implementing that in your project. After that look at generics. Generics shouldn't be to hard since you are already using List(Of T).